# Does anyone have Emacs style keybindings setup in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a .vssettings file that has emacs keybindings in it so that a member of our development team can use them.

Anyone already have one setup they can share?

Comment: This is the best I have came across: http://www.ubertoys.com/vsnetemacs/, though I am much more impressed with the VI plug-in: http://www.viemu.com/